# exclude two directories in glob.glob()

Tags: python, directory, glob

I have the following list of directories and sub-directories.

```
import glob
zipfiles = 'src/**/**/data.nq.gz'
filelist = glob.glob(zipfiles,recursive = True)
```

From this list, I need to exclude two directories namely 'src/27/' and 'src/c1/'

How do I do that?

P.S. src is a huge folder that contains tons of directories and subdirectories.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
filelist = [f for f in filelist if f[:7] not in ['src/27/', 'src/c1/']]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try

```
filelist = [file for file in filelist if not file.startswith("src/27/") and not file.startswith("src/c1/")]
```

Edit: Removed buggy solution that I first suggested.

Comment: This is buggy: if you remove an element whilst iterating, the position of the following elements will change.